# How can I fix small imperfections in paint over drywall?

Tags: drywall, repair

I need to repair some drywall and I'm looking to do it as quickly and cheaply as possible.  I'm renting a place and just want to make this look like it's not terrible.  If paint doesn't match exactly, not the end of the world.  I'm a complete beginner and just not sure where to begin.

How can I repair this as cheaply as possible?  There is only 1 tear where the drywall is showing, the rest just have the paint that came off.

Here is a picture of the wall:

[image: Here is a picture of the wall]

Answer (score 4):

You are in luck, because all drywall repairs are cheap. It's one of those trades in which the cost is almost all in the labor and the materials are just a small fraction.

For about $5 you can buy drywall joint compound, and use a spatula to apply it, then do a bit of sanding. DAP sells a drywall repair kit for $15 that includes the joint compound, the knife, and sandpaper. Can't get cheaper than that. Then you'll have to pay $15 for a quart of color-matching paint. It costs the same to buy color-matched paint than it costs to buy paint that does not match, so might as well get the matching.

Comment: To get color matched paint, cut off a bit of the torn up paper with the original paint on it, take it to the paint store, and ask them to match it. (Make sure they match the painted side, not the unpainted side. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Cheapest way I can think of fixing that tear is to put a little white glue under it and push the paper back in place. Maybe a piece of masking tape over it to hold it in place while the glue dries.

Comment: Strikes me that the masking tape may well tear the paper right back off when you're attempting to remove it...